# How to make a cross-reference to a custom field in Microsoft Word for Mac Office 365?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a custom object which creates a Sequence field. I use it to number questions in my exams.

I would like to reference to groups of questions, that is, the sequence fields. This way, as the order or numbering of the question changes, my reference to them is automatically updated.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution [here](https://word.tips.net/T001391_Inserting_a_Cross-Reference_to_Text.html), courtesy of word.tips.net.

A cross-reference to a custom field can be made the same way as a cross-reference to a text; that is, via bookmarks.

1. Assign a bookmark `BKMK` to the desired portion
2. On a Mac, press CMD+F9 to insert field brackets.
3. Inside the field brackets, type `ref` followed by a space, and then the bookmark name, e.g.: `{ ref BKMK }`

That's it!

To view the results, toggle field codes to off (right click and select the option on Mac). Then press F9 to update the field to see your result.